# OctoberCMS | How to disable Loading Indicator on AJAX extra features

Tags: ajax, octobercms, october-partial

On my project I need to use AJAX extra features, that are a form validation and flash messages... But I don't wanna see the loading indicator on the top of a page

[image]

How to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove it for every page, you can just hide it with CSS

```
.stripe-loading-indicator{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: Yeah xD it's obvious... but I want to disable programmatically xD